# css responsive fluid html font size based on rem

Tags: html, css

I want to implement the example from [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-calc-in-css/) based on rems. This is what I got so far. However, the scaling does not work as intended, and the font size increases only tiny amounts. What is the mistake?

```
html {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  html {
    font-size: calc(1rem + 2 * ((100vw - 20rem) / 680));
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  html {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
}
```

I assume that `2 * ((100vw - 20rem) / 680)` returns a px value. If that's true. How can I change it to return `rem` instead?

Edited to add some clarifications:
I want to use `rem` instead of `px` because this allows the user to overwrite the default font size in the browser.

The term `2 * ((100vw - 20rem) / 680)` is between `0` and `2` (1 rem equals 16px on normal font size). This is what I want to achieve. I want to have `font-size: 1rem + [0, 2]rem` between 320 and 1000px viewport width. A linearly increasing rem function based on the viewport width.

Here is a [link to a sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-montalcini-1v8gd).

Edit 2:
I think what I want to achieve is not possible. If the user increases the default font size by 50%, I want the scaling factor also increase by 50%: `font-size: 1rem + [0, 2 * 1.5]rem`.

The current problem is that the part `2 * ((100vw - 20rem) / 680))` needs to be rem based. This is not possible because there is no way in CSS to strip the unit. If I could strip the unit, I could do this: `2rem * strip-unit((100vw - 20rem) / 680))`

Comment: rem also return px value. nothing is wrong in that piece of code. if you want to see significant difference in font size then reduce the denominator value. This is simple maths

Comment: @devd thanks for your answer. Changing the denominator value does not help in my case. I edited my question to provide more details.

Comment: font-size: calc(1rem + 2 * ((100vw - 2rem) / 120))

Comment: you should be setting the html fontsize to 100% - a rem value is related to the Root Element ie the HTML element and so you are referencing the HTML element in the HTML element. Setting the font-size to 100% will allow whatever the users browser default setting to be and that will then be referenced by other elements as 1rem.

Comment: @gavgrif yes thanks, it works the same with 1rem, however.

Comment: @devd yes this changes the scaling factor. The problem is, however, that if the user changes the default font size by 50% for example, the scaling factor doesn't scale by 50% as well.

Comment: Why would you let the user ever change the default `font-size`? If you intend to allow the user to scale `font-size` up/down simply apply that new `font-size` to `<body>` so it can be inherited by all tags (with the exception of `<input>`, `<button>`,  and `<select>` which actually needs explicit CSS in order to inherit font properties.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a responsive font size then you can use View Width too, no need to use calc or rem for that.

Just change this so you can try it out:

```
HTML {
  font-size: 5vw;
}
```

View width goes from 0 to 100 so you know how much room you have to work with.

edit: I personally haven't found out how to scale on both axis yet but just the X-axis works good enough in most cases.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea. The problem with your suggestion is, however, that if the user changes the default font size, the actual font size will remain the same.

Comment: you mean change the font size in the browser setting? I don't think CSS alone will be able to fix that, but JS surely will =)!.

Comment: Yes exactly. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for fluid fonts I got from [Creating a Fluid Type Scale with CSS Clamp](https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/fluid-type-scale-with-css-clamp/)

After some tweaking I ended up with the following Sass code to generate the clamp function.

```
    /*
   From https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/fluid-type-scale-with-css-clamp/
   Generates the css clamp function.  
   Focused on font-size, but may be used for margins and padding

   Usage:  
      clamped(min-size-px, max-size-px, min-browser-width-px, max-browser-width-px)
      font-size: clamped(26px, 36px, 600px, 1200px);    
      font-size: clamped(26px, 36px);      //using width default values
Output:
    font-size: clamp(1.63rem, 1.11vw + 1.28rem, 2.25rem);

*/

@use "sass:math";
@use "sass:map";

// Default min-mix browser width values for clamped function
$default-min-bp: 500px;           
$default-max-bp: 1400px;           

// Convert pixels to rems.
@function to-rems($px) {
  $rems: math.div($px, 16px) * 1rem;
  @return $rems;
}


//round a to number of decimal places.
@function rnd($number, $places: 0) {
  $n: 1;
  @if $places > 0 {
    @for $i from 1 through $places {
      $n: $n * 10;
    }
  }
  @return math.div(math.round($number * $n), $n);
}

// Generate css for clamp
@function clamped($min-px, $max-px, $min-bp: $default-min-bp, $max-bp: $default-max-bp) {
  $slope: math.div($max-px - $min-px, $max-bp - $min-bp);
  $slope-vw: rnd($slope * 100, 2);
  $intercept-rems: rnd(to-rems($min-px - $slope * $min-bp), 2);
  $min-rems: rnd(to-rems($min-px), 2);
  $max-rems: rnd(to-rems($max-px), 2);
  @return clamp(#{$min-rems}, #{$slope-vw}vw + #{$intercept-rems}, #{$max-rems});
}
```